# koma-script style section titles

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Currently I'm using

```tex
\newcommand{\newchapter}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt} \vspace*{-0.30cm} \\ \textbf{\textcolor{red}{\Large #1}} \vspace*{-0.15cm}\\\rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt}\par}
```

to make section like headers. But it feels wrong doing so while latex has the concept of real `sections` (and by using restyled sections the content is just much more portable (copy paste it to another document)).

See here a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec} % LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{multicol} % use \begin{multicols}{num} text \end{multicols} and the text will be automatically distributed
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}                 % header and footer
\usepackage{xcolor}

% ----- Settings -----
\KOMAoptions{
    paper=a4,           % set papersize
    paper=landscape,    % set paperformat
    fontsize=6.6pt,       % set fontsize
    parskip=half,       % half a line will seperate paragraphs
    headings=normal,    % headings in normalsize
    twoside=false,      % onesided document
    twocolumn=false,    % one columned pages
    numbers=autoendperiod, % automatic punctuation in outline
}

% turn off header and footer
\pagestyle{empty}

\areaset{835pt}{585pt}

% indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

% big red titles for chapters
\newcommand{\newchapter}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt} \vspace*{-0.30cm} \\ \textbf{\textcolor{red}{\Large #1}} \vspace*{-0.15cm}\\\rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt}\par}

% blue titles for single topics within a chapter
\newcommand{\topic}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}

% green and bold text for important concepts
\newcommand{\term}[2][]{%
    \if n#1\else\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1\fi%
    \textbf{\textcolor{green!50!black}{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.01pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\newchapter{NewChapter}
\topic{Topic}
\term{Term}

\newpage
force pagebreak

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and the page output:
[image: pdf output]

(don't wonder about the maybe weird fontsize/papersize, it is supposed to be this way to fit as much as possible on the page)

So I'd like to use `section` instead of `newchapter`, `subsection` instead of `topic` and `paragraph` instead of `term`.

Is there a way to do this (and if yes how)? Note the missing linebreaks after `topic` and `term` (but I'd be ok if these linebreaks couldn't be prevented)

Sorry if this is a pretty obvious question, but I already looked into `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\setkomafont` (would work for the colors, but I'm not sure about the `hangindent` (term) and the `\rule` (newchapter) especially the `\rule` after the chapter text).

Note: I'm compiling with `lualatex`, but this shouldn't have a relevant effect.

**Note for Bounty:**
`newChapter` and `topic` are solved (see `esdd`s answer), but I'm still struggling  with the `hangindent` for `\term`. I know I can do `\newcommand{\term}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}` but still I'd like to use `\paragraph` in the document-body so that its easy to change the formatting.

Comment: Decided to go without indentation (boldface and color are highlighting enough to find the terms/topics fast enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for the `section` and `subsection` headings:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- not used in the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

% ----- Settings -----
\KOMAoptions{
    %paper=a4,% default
    paper=landscape,
    fontsize=6.6pt,
    %parskip=half,% <- overwritten by \setparsizes
    headings=normal,
    %twoside=false,% default with scrartcl
    %twocolumn=false,% default
    %numbers=autoendperiod,% default
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\areaset{835pt}{585pt}
\setparsizes{0pt}{0pt}{1em plus 1fil}% indentation

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\partnumdepth}% unnumbered sections etc.

% big red titles for sections
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=0pt,
  afterindent=false,
  runin=false,
  font=\rmfamily\color{red}\Large
]{section}

\newcommand*{\originalsectionlinesformat}{}
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}\textcolor{black}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt}}\nopagebreak\par\vskip-.1cm#4\nopagebreak\par\vskip-.3cm  \textcolor{black}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt}}}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

% blue titles for subsections:
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1ex,
  font=\rmfamily\color{blue}
]{subsection}

% green and bold text for important concepts:
\newcommand{\term}[2][]{%
    \if n#1\else\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1\fi%
    \textbf{\textcolor{green!50!black}{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.01pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\section{NewSection}
\subsection{Topic}
\term{Term}

\newpage
force pagebreak
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\sectionlinesformat`, I forgot it existed, this is helpful. I've been using an evil hack for colored section lines in some special reports. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks didn't knew of `\sectionlinesformat`. Any ideas how to set the `hangindent` (for the content) for the `\term` command? Just being curious, does it matter to define `\originalsectionlinesformat` as a latex command before `\let`? And is there a difference between setting the font via the `font` key in `RedeclareSectionCommand` and setting the font via `setkomafont`?

Comment: In addition I see it works, but I don't quite understand how it works (the line where the rules etc are created). So as far as I read it, it's: make a rule, then enter vertical mode and insert .1cm space (to avoid a pagebreak here `\nopagebreak`), insert the section title (why are the `\par` needed here? as far as I understand we already are in vertical mode), then enter vertical mode, insert -.3cm space (again avoid pagebreak) and the second rule.

So basically the two things confusing me are the `\par` and why set the `parfillskip`length? (sorry for so many questions but I'm curious)

Comment: I have no idea for the `\term`. Additinally I am not sure, if this is (or should be) a heading, because you use it inline.

I use `\newcommand*{\originalsectionlinesformat}{}` to ensure that `\originalsectionlinesformat` was undefined. 

If you want, you can remove the `\par` after  `#4`, because we should be there already in vertical mode.

Comment: Your `parskip=half` and my `\setparsizes{0pt}{0pt}{1em plus 1fil}` (do not change `\parindent` and/or `\parskip` manually!) set `\parfillskip` to `1em plus 1fil). Therefore `1em` free horizontal space at the end of each paragraph is required. To avoid warnings regarding overfull `hbox`es, I change `\parfillskip` in `\sectionlinesformat`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I think I'll start a bounty for the `\term` (it should be used inline but only as paragraph like heading (runin)), since no matter what I search I cannot find a way to apply `hangindent` on the section/paragraph content the proper way.